# How to see what the is being compared in a if statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm having a problem with some vba code. 
I have a if statement that doesn't treat the same content equally.
e.g: 0,1 equals 0,1, but a re-run 0,1 does not equal 0,1 
(this values are shown by MVBA)

The code is long so before posting it i would like to know if it's possible to see the machine perspective in a if statement (hex, ascii...). This because, although the debug is telling me they are the same (through msgbox, vartype, etc), the if statement is not activated.

```
    pseudo code:
    x = 0,0000001 * 1*10^6 (which equals 0,1)
    y = 0,0001 * 1*10^3 (which also equals 0,1)

    if statement:
         x doesn't enter
         y does
    end if
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant bit of the code (specifically the `if` statement conditional). Best guess at the moment is that the two numbers aren't coming out exactly the same because of rounding errors (which is what you should expect with floating point numbers), but it's not possible to say until we get more detail.

Comment: If you compare `Double`s, the two numbers might not be identical due to rounding errors. It is safer to use `Abs(x - y) < epsilon`, where `epsilon` is a predefined tolerance. [Useful (but somewhat long) read](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: In the *debugger* `x` may look like `0.1` but its not; you can see with `Z = x - 0.1` after which `Z` will not be `0` - See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the floating-point implementation may not be able to represent those number accurately due to the fact that they are encoded in a base 2 representation.

If you want to compare them, I would suggest using `Cdec` (wich converts to [`Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx), a VBA custom base 10 floating-point)

```
Debug.Print (0.0000001 * 1 * 10 ^ 6) = (0.0001 * 1 * 10 ^ 3) ' False
Debug.Print CDec(0.0000001 * 1 * 10 ^ 6) = CDec(0.0001 * 1 * 10 ^ 3) ' True
```

While they both display `0.1`, in fact `0.0000001 * 1 * 10 ^ 6` flaoting-point value is `0x3FB9999999999999` whereas `0.0001 * 1 * 10 ^ 3` returns `0x3FB999999999999A`.

I'd recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)